# .NET :- Matching object to Ojects in Hashset using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Objective is to develop a manpower planning class that assigns work to employees
based on their skills.

- We have task to assign in the following Task (variable).

  ```
  IEnumerable<Task> task = repository.Tasks.ToList();
  ```

and taskSmall contains TaskId and Skill Id : -

```
Id  SkillRequired
1   1
2   2
```

- Now we have list of People

  ```
  IEnumerable<Person> people = repository.People.ToList();
  ```

where people contains fields like `Person Name` , `HashSet<Skill> Skills`. One person can have multiple skills.

- Problem is we need to match the skill required for task from `task` and skills of every person from `HashSet` and we need to retrieve `TaskId` and `Person Name` after assigning.
- Each task requires a single person to perform it. If skill require for task repeats then we need to check which person is not busy ( or not assigned any task) to complete that task based on skills.

Comment: What is `taskSmall`?

Comment: Try IEqulityComparer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: How do you want to handle person A having skills 1 & 2, person B having skill 1 when you have a task with skill 2 and a task with skill 1?

Comment: @NetMage if you assign task with skill 2 to person A then he will be busy and you left with another task and person B. If left out person have skill to complete remaining task then you should assign him

Comment: But if you assign tasks in order, you could assign task with skill 1 to person A leaving no one to do task with skill 2 - I take it you want to avoid that?

Comment: Ah but the issue is both people could have done the tasks on day one if assigned properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would flatten the `Person` `Skills` so that you have each person with one of their skills:

```
var peopleSkill = people.SelectMany(p => p.Skills.Select(skill => new { skill, p }));
```

Then I would find all possible sets of people that match the skill needed for a task, and order by number of skills for the person so that fewer skilled people are preferred for assignment first:

```
var matchings = task.GroupJoin(peopleSkill,
                               t => t.SkillId,
                               ps => ps.skill.SkillId,
                               (task, pss) => new { task, people = pss.Select(ps => ps.p).OrderBy(p => p.Skills.Count) })
                    .OrderBy(tp => tp.people.Count());
```

Then you can go through the possible assigments and assign the first available person to each task:

```
var assigned = new Dictionary<Task, Person>();
var usedPeople = new HashSet<Person>();
foreach (var m in matchings) {
    foreach (var tryPerson in m.people) {
        if (!usedPeople.Contains(tryPerson)) {
            assigned.Add(m.task, tryPerson);
            usedPeople.Add(tryPerson);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This provides an `IEnumerable` of all tasks either paired with a `Person` or `null` if unassigned:

```
var ans = task.Select(t => new { task = t, person = assigned.TryGetValue(t, out var p) ? p : default });
```

Comment: You are right , joining table with skillId but I am reading data from CSV file. So that we dont have PK and FK (Foreign key). Doesnt really matters but the task will duplicate if we continued.

Comment: @ChrisJ I don't understand. `GroupJoin` doesn't care about keys, just about the lambda methods that tell it what should match up, and it should work fine with data from a CSV file.